# How to update Laravel Eloquent column cast as collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10, laravel-collection

I am using Laravel 10.

I am utilizing casting for a JSON column in the following manner:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
  protected $casts = [
    'meta' => 'collection', // here
  ];
}
```

When attempting to update a value within a collection directly, for instance:

```php
$model->meta->put('test', 100);
$model->save();
```

Nothing occurs.

When I assign the variable as it is, it functions correctly.

```php
$model->meta = ['test' => 100];
$model->save();
```

However what if I only need to update/add a single element?

I have discovered the following workaround, but is this the intended behavior?

```php
$meta = $model->meta;
$meta->put('test', 100);
$model->meta = $meta;
$model->save();
```

It appears that only direct assignment works in such a case, and it seems that the cast collection does not support any of its write functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution (Laravel 8.28 or higher)

**Need use [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\AsCollection`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Casts/AsCollection.html) instead of `'collection'`.**

In the [`$casts`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) array, you can define the types of individual keys. By specifying the classes of the types (where necessary), Laravel automatically handles the conversion. This is why the specific use of [`AsCollection::class`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Casts/AsCollection.html) is required.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\AsCollection;

class Item extends Model
{
  protected $casts = [
    'meta' => AsCollection::class, // automatically convert value of 'meta' to Collection::class
  ];
}
```

###### More information

- [Attribute Casting (list of casts)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) - Laravel Docs (10.x)
- [Array, Object and Collection casting](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-object-and-collection-casting) - Laravel Docs (10.x)
- [New casts added to Laravel 8](https://laravel-news.com/as-arrayobject-and-as-collection-custom-casts) - Laravel News
- [`AsCollection::class`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Casts/AsCollection.html) - Laravel API Docs

---

### Solution (Laravel 7.x or lower)

`AsCollection` is available by default in Laravel 8.x or higher versions. **If you need the collection feature in an older version, you will need to [create a custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) yourself.**

Or alternately can use [`'array'`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) cast:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
  protected $casts = [
    'meta' => 'array', // automatically convert value of 'meta' to array
  ];
}
```

###### More information

- [How to make Custom Cast](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) - Laravel Docs (7.x)

Answer (score 1):

try casting as collection `AsCollection`

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\AsCollection;


protected $casts = [
  'meta' => AsCollection::class,
  ...
];
```